# where is the css styling which captcha creates?

Tags: css, captcha

I just signed up for captcha. It gave me php code to display the captcha box on the page and code to put on the server. It works fine but the input box is misaligned (it might be based on the rest of the styling of the page.) I want to modify it manually but I can't.

When I do an inspect code in google chrome, it shows me the styling for the input box I needed. I unchecked a particular style

```
position: absolute!important
```

and it now looks fine. Now I need to actually modify the code. But it says the location is registration.php:1. Where is this? Registration.php is the file which creates the html code for the page and it does a "require" for a captcha php file. But I don't see the css style in that file either!

Comment: Can you post the relevant code (captcha php file)?

Comment: The file can be found at http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:phplib-Latest

Answer (score 0):

See these 2 images to see where the CSS could be coming from:

1- In Chrome console under the elements tab

[image: Chrome console]

2- In Chrome console under the resources tab

[image: Chrome console]